# How to split comma separated data into multiple lines

Tags: sql, split

I have a table Goods that stores the id, batch and type of goods. Goods with multiple IDs are of different types but belong to the same batch, so they are recorded together.

| id | batch | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123,124,128 | 1 | A,B,C |
| 456,555 | 2 | C |
| 678 | 3 | A,B |

I now want the following results, that is, split the data separated by commas into multiple rows(I use PieCloudDB Database), is there any way to achieve this?

| id | batch | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 123 | 1 | B |
| 123 | 1 | C |
| 124 | 1 | A |
| 124 | 1 | B |
| 124 | 1 | C |
| 128 | 1 | A |
| 128 | 1 | B |
| 128 | 1 | C |
| 456 | 2 | C |
| 555 | 2 | C |
| 678 | 3 | A |
| 678 | 3 | B |

I tried this, but the result I get is not exactly correct.

```
SELECT 
    unnest(string_to_array(g.id, ',')) AS id,
    g.batch,
    unnest(string_to_array(g.type, ',')) AS type
FROM 
    Goods g
JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(g.id, ',')) AS t(id) ON true
ORDER BY
    g.id;
```

My results:

| id | batch | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 124 | 1 | B |
| 128 | 1 | C |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 124 | 1 | B |
| 128 | 1 | C |
| 123 | 1 | A |
| 124 | 1 | B |
| 128 | 1 | C |
| 456 | 2 | C |
| 555 | 2 |  |
| 456 | 2 | C |
| 555 | 2 |  |
| 678 | 3 | A |
|  | 3 | B |

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the programming language you are using or would like answers in, and show any attempts you've made based on research you've done while attempting to solve this on your own.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without knowing what RDBMS or programming language you are using. We're not going to guess, especially since you have shown no effort on your part to solve the problem yourself. When asking a question that is related to code, the very first tag you should add is for the language or RDBMS you're using. The only tag you've added is the absolutely useless *split* tag.

Comment: I'm sorry, the RDBMS I am using cannot be searched in the tag sets.

Comment: If you can't provide any details, we can't help you. As I said before, the tag *split* is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL functions `unnest()` and `string_to_array()` to achieve this.(I searched and found that pieclouddb is compatible with PostgreSQL, I think this method should be useful)

```
WITH SplitIDs AS (
  SELECT unnest(string_to_array(id, ',')) AS id, batch
  FROM goods
),
SplitTypes AS (
  SELECT unnest(string_to_array(type, ',')) AS type, batch
  FROM goods
)
SELECT t1.id AS id, t1.batch, t2.type AS type
FROM SplitIDs t1
JOIN SplitTypes t2 ON t1.batch = t2.batch
ORDER BY id, type
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried and got the expected answer.